# Change navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have to do the following: I've a navigation with a logo in it, the HTML looks like this:

```
<nav id="navigation-main">
   <ul class="level_1 inside">
    <li class="class1">Menüpunkt</li>
    <li class="class2>">Menüpunkt</li>
    <li id="logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></li>        
    <li class="class3">Menüpunkt</li>
    <li class="clas4">Menüpunkt</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

on mobile devices the Logo should appear permanently on the website but not within the navigation, so I put it with jQuery out of the navi. On a remove it should appear back. But the remove should only appear, when the logo was put out of my navi:

```
var bildschirmbreite = $(window).width();
  if (bildschirmbreite <= 1180) {
    $("#logo a").appendTo("header").addClass("logo");
    $("#logo").remove();
  }  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var bildschirmbreite = $(window).width();
    if (bildschirmbreite <= 1180) {
        $("#logo a").appendTo("header").addClass("logo");
        $("#logo").remove();
        var resized = 1;
    }  
    if (bildschirmbreite >= 1180 && resized === 1) {
        $("#navigation-main .class2").after('<li id="logo"></li>');
        $(".logo").appendTo("#logo");
        $("#navigation-main").removeAttr("style");
    }
  });
});
```

At least I've a few problems: It appears just, when the resized-check doesn't appears in the last if. But then a  is put after .class2 with every resize-event. If I have the resize-chek with the if, the logo doesn't changed back.

So my question is: Whats wrong with my code and what do I have to do, that it appears correctly?

Here is a example at Codepen: http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/RRZWKO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here are things wrong with your code:

There's a typo in

> "class2>"

Also, the block following the if condition:

```
if (bildschirmbreite >= 1180 && resized === 1)
```

It will never be executed because resized will always be recognized as "undefined" (Try debugging this code with Chrome). To fix this, make changes to these line:

```
....
var resized = 1;
} 
if (bildschirmbreite >= 1180 && resized === 1)
```

To

```
....
window.resized = 1;
} 
if (bildschirmbreite >= 1180 && window.resized === 1)
```

Comment: that works fine, thanky you! but now (or still) i've the problem that the <li>-element appears permanently with a resize, is there a possibility to handle this?

Comment: Did you mean to remove <li> elements with this code `$("#navigation-main").removeAttr("style");`?

Comment: No, i mean this: `$("#navigation-main .class2").after('<li id="logo"></li>');`

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach, because its light-weight.

If you are using media screens in CSS then no need to use JQuery for it.

HTML Changes are :

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <nav id="navigation-main">
    <ul class="level_1 inside">
        <li class="class1">Menüpunkt</li>
        <li class="class2>">Menüpunkt</li>
        <li id="logo"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-leaf" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li class="class3">Menüpunkt</li>
        <li class="clas4">Menüpunkt</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

and CSS changes are

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation-main {
 background: red;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px;
}
ul li {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 20px; 
 padding: 5px;
}
#logo a {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 20px 40px;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
}
.logo
{
 display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 1179px) {
 #navigation-main {
   display: none;
}
.logo
{
 display:block;
}
}
```